# Problem with url_launcher in Flutter (I can't launch website)

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

Hi I have problem with url_launcher. I want to launch website and phone, but I can't and I don't know why. I tried to look in documentation but I couldn't find solution. I also changed website (google.com), but it didn't help.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

class contact extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _contactState createState() => _contactState();
}

class _contactState extends State<contact> {

  void _launch(command) async{
    if (await canLaunch(command)){
      await launch(command);
    }else{
      throw 'Cannot open $command';
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[800],
      body: Column(
        children: [
          SafeArea(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(06.0, 20.0, 70.0, 20.0),
              child: Text(
                "Skontaktuj się z nami!",
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 30.0,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontFamily: 'Raleway',
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 20.0),
          Center(
            child: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.phone, color: Colors.grey[900], size: 40.0),
              onPressed: (){
                _launch('https://www.google.com');
              },
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And dependencies:

```
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  url_launcher: ^5.7.10

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
```

And my error:

```
E/flutter ( 6469): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: Cannot open https://www.google.com
E/flutter ( 6469): #0      _contactState._launch (package:its_system/pages/contact.dart:15:7)
E/flutter ( 6469): <asynchronous suspension>
```

Thanks for helping me!

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks fine.
The error shown here is the result of the `canLaunch` method returning false.

My guess here is that you're testing your app on an Emulator not having any Browser installed. Try this code on a physical device or on a newly created emulator with a Browser installed and it should work

Comment: Today I connected real phone to my app and it still doesn't working. Do You have maybe others solutions? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `Uri.parse(PASS_YOUR_WEB_URL_HERE)` like below.

```
void _launch(command) async{
    if (await canLaunchUrl(Uri.parse(command))){
      await launchUrl(Uri.parse(command));
    }else{
      throw 'Cannot open $command';
    }
  }
```